# Why can't I print my indexPath.row swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is where I initialize my array of strings:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Butikker")                                    
    self.shopItems = [String]()                        
    databaseRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children {                 
                    let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                    let dictionary = snap.value as! [String: AnyObject]                   
                    self.shopItems.append(dictionary["Name"] as! String)

                }
})
```

This is my **tableview**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5 
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
                print(self.shopItems[indexPath.row])
                cell.textLabel?.text = self.shopItems[0]
        }
        return cell
}
```

My question is, why does my app crash when I try to print `shopItem[index.row]` and how would I solve this?

Comment: Did you try printing `shopItems` itself and see if it has those elements which you are looking for? Always the first step is to print the array and then share that also in the question.

Comment: The String array shopItems contains two string values. I am able to load the into my tableview if i cell.textLabel?.text = self.shopItems([0] or [1]]

Comment: so what is the value of `indexPath.row` before it crashes. That will tell you why it is crashing.

Comment: my indexPath.row wont print out anything, the error says that the index is out of range

Comment: So did you add a `print` statement as `print(indexPath.row)` before your other print statement? By the way why are you doing `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(`? Why don't do without that?

Comment: Because it takes time before the array shopItems has a value. The array that is appended are retrieved from my FirebaseDatabase

Comment: If that is the case, then you should reload your tableview after getting values in `databaseRef.observe` method. This is wrong way to do it. Also make sure you are returning  `shopItems.count` as number of rows in delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is going to solve your problems, but I have some basic improvements to your code that are probably going to prevent your app generally from crashing.

1.: after fetching a snapshot from Firebase I would always check if it actually exists; you can do that by calling `if !snapshot.exists() { return }` and in the for-in-loop `if !child.exists() { return }`. Before the return statement you can implement your error handling if you wish to. That means if for any reason there is no snapshot retrievable, it's going to stop the code from running.

2.: I would always get the snapshot values with an if-let-statement. This could be part of your problem as well. Simply call:

```
if let dictionary = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
  // do whatever you want to do if the dictionary can be created
} else { print("For some reason couldn't initialize the dictionary.")}
```

That also prevents your app from crashing (just in case) and can tell you if it can't find the value you need.

3.: Don't rely on executing the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath()-method asynchronously and with a delay. If you have a bad internet connection, it's not unlikely that the app is going to need more time to load and the data won't appear. Instead, call after the for-in-loop in your first part of code this method: `tableView.reloadData() // replace tableView with whatever your tableView is called`. That means that every time there's a new value, it's going to reload the data automatically so that you don't have to worry about losing the data on the way.

And to actually solve the problem you're asking about: obviously, the index of the indexPath.row is out of range and I think I know why: is it possible that in the numberOfRowsInSection method you're either not calling `shopItems.count` at all or maybe not asynchronously? 
If not, you could test it by calling in the cellForRowAtIndexPath()-method

```
print("Number of shops items: \(shopItems.count); Current index path. \(indexPath.row)")
```

This is at least going to give you all the important values for solving your problem. Hope I could help.